# What the difference between dojo.byId and dijit.byId?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Each time am trying the get the value of an element in my page, I have an error as is undefined: I have tried `dijit.byId('myid').innerHTML('loading...');`

I get an error
but when i do the same using jquery, it works `$­('#myid').html('loading ...')`

And what is the equivalent of this `$('#myid').html()` in dojo?
Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dijit.byId` returns a *dijit* object by some id.

`dojo.byId` is the equivalent of `$()`. To get/set it's HTML, use

```
dojo.byId("my_id").innerHTML
dojo.byId("my_id").innerHTML = some_text`
```

*Note that `dojo.byId` is just a wrapper around `document.getElementById`, so you can use all the basic functions.*

Comment: DojoCampus has a detailed article on *jsId, dijit.byId() and dojo.byId()*: http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/05/06/jsid-dijitbyid-and-dojobyid/

Comment: Should qualify that `dojo.byId` is the equivalent of `$()` presumably in Prototype; jQuery's `$()` is more along the lines of `dojo.query`.  I've written about some common points of confusion between dojo base and Dijit as well, maybe it'll help: http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/of-dijits-and-dom-nodes/

Answer (score 3):

```
dijit.byId("my_id") ----> returns the widget associated with the domNode.
dojo.byId("my_id") -----> returns the domNode itself.
```

### To access the domNode using dijit:

```
dijit.byId("my_id").domNode.innerHTML
```